# Kivy: Using custom event

Tags: python, kivy

I want to use DropDown for selection function for next using. In my code it is mean that:

- I press button *Create*
- Function *DropDownMenu.on_create()* sent event *on_create_folder*
- *DropDownButton.on_create_folder()* catches event

But function DropDownButton.on_create_folder() is not activated by event. How is problem in my code?

```
Builder.load_string('''
<FolderDropDownMenu>:
    Button:
        text: 'Create'
        on_release: root.on_create('inst', 'val')
    Button:
        text: 'Remove'
        on_release: root.on_remove('inst', 'val')
''')
# dropdown menu
class DropDownMenu(DropDown):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FolderDropDownMenu, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.register_event_type('on_create_folder')

    def on_create_folder(self):
        pass

    def on_create(self, inst, val):
        self.dispatch('on_create_folder')
        return
# main button
class DropDownButton(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwarg):
        super(FolderDropDownButton, self).__init__(**kwarg)
        self.dropdown = FolderDropDownMenu()
        self.dropdown.bind(on_create_folder = lambda *largs: self.on_create_folder)
        . . .
        . . .
        return

    def on_create_folder(self, inst, val):
        . . .
        . . .
        return
```

Comment: I think you are missing "Folder" in "class DropDownMenu" (and same for DropDownButton), though i don't think that's the cause of your issue, but when i fix that in my test, I'm not sure DropDown is what you want to use, but there is too much to guess here to make it a workable example, please give more details or (preferably) provide a short but complete example.

Comment: @Tshirtman In real using event I had chaos in function names. After solving it I catch event without problems. Can You see my question: "Kivy: Parameter of callback function" and explein me it?